# How to Loop through a Table and Act on the Text in Each Cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a JSON object from the data in a table. I want to loop through each row and extract the text in each cell and add it to the object. My code below loops through the rows and cells, outputting the text but I need to stop at each cell and do something with it's value.

```
<table id="socialLinkTable" border=1>
<thead>
  <th>Type</th><th>url</th><th>Value</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Facebook</td><td>www.facebook.com</td><td><button id='delete' onclick="deleteRow(this)" >Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Twitter</td><td>www.twitter.com</td><td><button id='delete' onclick="deleteRow(this)" >Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Instagram</td><td>www.instagram.com</td><td><button id='delete' onclick="deleteRow(this)" >Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LinkedIn</td><td>www.linkedin.com</td><td><button id='delete' onclick="deleteRow(this)" >Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

function deleteRow(elem) {

  //$(elem).closest("tr").remove();

  $("#socialLinkTable tr").each(function() {
    $(this).children("td").each(function() {
      console.log($(this)[0].innerText);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` this will give you all the rows of the table.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/orhjg42p/ The code you've written already DOES go through each cell and gets the text. What problem are you having?

Comment: Would you like to look up the jQuery method [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/)? It might be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it help?

```js
var objRow={};

$("#socialLinkTable tbody tr").each(function(index1) {
  var objCol = {}
  $(this).children("td").each(function(index2) {
    objCol[$('th:eq(' + index2 + ')').text()] = $(this).text().trim();
  });
  objRow[index1] = objCol;
});

console.log(objRow);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="socialLinkTable" border=1>
  <thead>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>url</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Facebook</td>
      <td>www.facebook.com</td>
      <td><button id='delete' onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Twitter</td>
      <td>www.twitter.com</td>
      <td><button id='delete' onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Instagram</td>
      <td>www.instagram.com</td>
      <td><button id='delete' onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LinkedIn</td>
      <td>www.linkedin.com</td>
      <td><button id='delete' onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and even creating the object. Kudos for reading the whole question!

Comment: I had to change to var objRow={}; to var objRow=[];. When I deserialzed the string, it complained about it not being in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery method `.map()` and array method `.reduce()` as follows:

```
//headings (keys)
const headings = $('table th').map((i,th) => th.textContent).get();

//Now get object
const objTable = $('table tr:has(td)')
.map(
    (i,tr) => 
    $(tr).find('td').map((j,td) => ({[headings[j]]:td.textContent})).get()
    .reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, cur), {})
).get();
console.log( objTable );
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(function() {
    //headings (keys)
    const headings = $('table th').map((i,th) => th.textContent).get();
    
    //Now get object
    const objTable = $('table tr:has(td)')
    .map(
        (i,tr) => 
        $(tr).find('td').map((j,td) => ({[headings[j]]:td.textContent})).get()
        .reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, cur), {})
    ).get();
    console.log( objTable );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="socialLinkTable" border=1>
<thead>
  <th>Type</th><th>url</th><th>Value</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Facebook</td><td>www.facebook.com</td><td><button id='delete' onclick="deleteRow(this)" >Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Twitter</td><td>www.twitter.com</td><td><button id='delete' onclick="deleteRow(this)" >Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Instagram</td><td>www.instagram.com</td><td><button id='delete' onclick="deleteRow(this)" >Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LinkedIn</td><td>www.linkedin.com</td><td><button id='delete' onclick="deleteRow(this)" >Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```